Examples of knots with a high-dimensional component of the character variety
For a knot $K$ let $\mathcal{X}(K)$ be the $\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb{C})$ character variety.
We say it is high dimensional if there's a component with dimension $> 1$; one easy way to find such $\mathcal{X}(K)$ is to choose $K$ to be a connect sum.
Are there known examples of specific prime knots with high-dimensional character varieties? I'm particularly interested in diagrams of these with relatively few crossings so I can compute some things.
Cooper and Long [1, Section 7] explain how to construct a hyperbolic (in particular, prime) knot $K$ with $\mathcal{X}(K)$ high dimensional. However as far as I can tell their construction doesn't immediately lead to an explicit knot diagram of $K$.
[1] Cooper, D.; Long, D. D., Remarks on the (A)-polynomial of a knot, J. Knot Theory Ramifications 5, No. 5, 609-628 (1996). ZBL0890.57012.

To get a high dimensional character variety, you need (usually many) incompressible surfaces in the knot complement. This usually makes the knot complicated , as with connected sums.

Is there a good source that discusses this more precisely? I know there’s the boundary slopes are boundary slopes result in the original A-polynomial papers, but I feel like I don’t understand why it really works.

Results about surfaces associated to ideal points of character varieties were first discussed in a series of papers by Culler and Shalen (based on ideas of Bass). If the character variety of a knot has dimension at least 2, then the knot is “large”, meaning that it has a closed incompressible surface. I’m not sure where they originally proved this, but it was certainly in “Dehn surgery on knots” by Culler Gordon Luecke Shalen (the proof in that paper has different arguments for small and large knots).

According to Section 8 of the Cooper-Long paper Remarks on the A-polynomial of a knot, the character variety of the knot shown below has a component of dimension at least two.  (We take $p = 2$ in the construction they give between Lemma 8.1 and Theorem 8.2.)


One way to achieve this is to take a band sum of knots whose $SU(2)$ character variety has dimension at least one and is non-trivial (which is any non-trivial knot ) and which is prime (by taking sufficiently complicated bands). Miyazaki has shown that  these knots are ribbon concordant to the connected sum. Then the $SU(2)$ (and hence $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$) character variety has high dimension by Proposition 1.15 of this paper.
Unfortunately to get prime knots, the bands will have to be fairly complicated.
